# Implementation of SINC filter using Integrate results in incorrect output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs, complex

**Bug introduced in 6.0, persisting through 13.3.1.**

---

This is SINC filter, integrate $|H|^2$ from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

MMA CODE, Result = 7.27956e-12

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
osr = 16;z = E^(I*w);
h = (1-z^-osr)/(1-z^-1)/osr;
N[Integrate[0.5*(Abs[h^5])^2, {w, -π, π}]/(2*π/osr), 5]
```

MATLAB CODE, Result = 0.2156

```matlab
clear;clc;
syms w
osr = 16;
z=exp(1j*w);
h=(1-z^-osr)/(1-z^-1)/osr;
vpa(int(0.5*(abs(h^5))^2,-pi,pi)/(2*pi/osr),5)
```

Further, if increasing `OSR=32`, MMA will come up with a more outrageous answer; while if decreasing the order to 4, `h^4`, MMA's result is correct. Could anyone help explain this, thank you!

Comment: `NIntegrate[0.5*(Abs[h^5])^2, {w, -π, π}]/(2*π/osr)`.

Comment: To close voters, this isn't a simple mistake at all, it's a bug, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in *v6*. To be precise, a regression is first introduced in *v5.1* or *v5.2*:

[image]

[image]

Then it evolves to a bug in *v6*:

[image]

As shown by Syed in comment above, if you just need numeric solution, then using `NIntegrate` instead is a possible work-around:

```
NIntegrate[1/2 (Abs[h^5])^2, {w, -π, π}]/(2 π/osr)
(* 0.215606 *)
```

It's also possible to fix the issue in `Integrate`. We just need `ComplexExpand`:

```
osr = 16; z = E^(I*w);
h = (1 - z^-osr)/(1 - z^-1)/osr;
Integrate[1/2 (Abs[h^5])^2 // ComplexExpand, {w, -π, π}]/(2 π/osr)
(* 1852037801/8589934592 *)
N@%
(* 0.215606 *)
```